# Bluetooth communication not sending correctly

Tags: android

I am using code found here (unmodified) http://goldenhillbooks.com/blog/?p=59#respond.  The data looks like it is sent and received but not the correct data.  It is like the baud rate is not correct.  The device I am connecting to has a baud rate of 9600 and does successfully receive and send data correctly using other Apps like Blueterm.

Comment: Edit an example of the expected vs actual data into your post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  The MCU I was communicating with is will turning LED on when command from blue tooth.  I was getting power from the computers USB and it was enough power to the Blue tooth connection but not when the LED light.

Comment: That's extremely surprising (ie, probably coincidental) unless this a a serious LED "light source" rather than simply a common small indicator LED.

Comment: It is a LED strip, and I was split of the device to charge the phone.  It was most likely the phone was the issue.

Comment: Ok, an LED strip can indeed add up to more than USB spec current limits.